# Database schema with categories, subcategories and products

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, database-schema

I am looking for the best way to create clothing store database that has categories, subcategories and products.

```
    Categories: mens, womens, kids, home
    subcategories: tops, bottoms, shoes, accessories, art
    products: 10 different tops, 10 different bottoms, 10 different shoes, 10 different accessories and 10 different pieces of art for the home category.
```

I wand to display categories on first page, subcategories on second page and then products on the third page based on the selected categories and subcategories, just like a online store.
products should only belong to one subcategory.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How far have you gotten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend structuring your category table like below:

```
Category
----------
CategoryId
ParentCategoryId --nullable
CategoryName
```

I'm not sure what you want to store in products so it's hard for me to tell you how to design that, but at a minimum you should have a CategoryId column in there.  I would leave it to your business logic to force products to only use SubCategories (aka records from the Category table that have a `ParentCategoryId`)

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I figured out how to make the tables now. I now realize how easy this question was. Sorry, I am a beginner.